# Does Varchar(x) count white space?

Tags: sqldatatypes

I am looking for a cut and dry answer. I have seen posts that say it doesn't count ending white space or some say it doesn't count leading white space.

example "if this was the example" would this be a varchar(19) or varchar(23)?

Comment: If your question is about ending or leading white space, why doesn't your example have both? Like " if this was the example " would it be varchar(23) or varchar(25)?

Comment: @thursdaysgeek because I am not worried about ending and leading spaces really i want to know in general. I wanted my questions to focus more towards the problem i am facing not the examples i am finding.

Comment: Oh, ok.  Your title just mentioned white space, but since your question mentioned leading and ending white space, that made it seem like what you were interested in it.  That might be the reason for the downvote: your example doesn't match your explanation of what you are asking (although the example does match your title).

Comment: @thursdaysgeek i am just happy i got my answer. I needed to be 100% sure.  I wasn't confident in what i read. I will suffer the points lost!

Comment: @jackncoke Don't worry, I removed your downvote because I had the same question and my search led me to this, so it answered my question. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`VARCHAR(23)`, since space also needs to be stored for the sentence to stay the same.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is Yes it accepts white spaces. And the output is varchar(23)

Answer (score 1):

varchar's can take into account spaces, so yes it does need varchar(23).